# Alternative of heredoc syntax

Tags: php, html, heredoc

Is there anything in HTML like heredoc syntax in PHP?
Because in case of a span with long text I have to use br tags each time I want to have a linebreak.

Comment: use a div with fixed width, which'd cause the text to wrap itself. Heredocs do not "wrap" text for you. They're simply a way of outputting (or assigning) multiple lines of text without having to do repeated string concatenation.

Comment: Use `<p>` elements, and allow the browser to wrap the text inside some containing element. Or is that too easy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<pre>` tag sounds like what you're looking for. From MDN: [Whitespaces inside this element are displayed as typed.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre)

```
<pre>
Hello
 !!!
World
</pre>
```

becomes

```
Hello
 !!!
World
```

You can also use the [`white-space` CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) to achieve a similar effect on any tag, though it behaves slightly differently.

```
<span style="white-space:pre;">Hello
 !!!
World
</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use *spans with long text*, use paragraphs, or parse your text as if it were [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/), like here:

```
Some Line

Some Other Line
```

will render to:

```
<p>Some Line</p>
<p>Some Other Line</p>
```